# Find and delete all the directories named "test" in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have many directories named "test" and I would like to remove them.

I know how to find them and print them using:

```
find . -name test -print
```

Now, how to do I remove the directories?

---

Please note that I have files in the directory as well and they must be removed as well.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) does all the magic:

```
find . -name test -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --
```

`xargs` executes the command passed as parameters, with the arguments passed to stdin.

This is using [`rm -r`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) to delete the directory and all its children.

The [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean) denotes the end of the arguments, to avoid a path starting with `-` from being treated as an argument.

`-print0` tells `find` to print `\0` characters instead of newlines; and `-0` tells `xargs` to treat only `\0` as argument separator.

This is calling `rm` with many directories at once, avoiding the overhead of calling `rm` separately for each directory.

---

As an alternative, `find` can also run a command for each *selected* file:

```
find . -name test -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

And this one, with better performance, since it will call `rm` with **multiple directories at once**:

```
find . -name test -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

(Note the `+` at the end; this one is equivalent to the `xargs` solution.)

Comment: Excellent answer, especially the `+` in find.  I had no idea, definitely wished I'd had known that long ago.

Comment: watch out for the last command, somehow it deleted some files. the `xargs` command worked well.

Answer (score 26):

```
find /path/to/dir -name "test" -type d -delete
```

- **-name:** looks for the name passed. You can use `-regex` for providing names based on regular expressions
- **-type:** looks for file types. `d` only looks for directories
- **-delete:** action which deletes the list found.

**Alternatively:**

```
find /path/to/dir -name "test" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

As **J.F. Sebastian** stated in the comments:

*You could use `+` instead of `\;` to pass more than one directory at a time.*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention that these directories may have files. I couldn't delete some of them because of "find: cannot delete `./start': Directory not empty" error

Comment: @garbagecollection I added an update.

Comment: you could use `+` instead of `\;` to pass more than one directory at a time.

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian Good point. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

yet another way to do this is

```
find . -name test -exec rm -R "{}" \;
```

A helpfull link on find : http://www.softpanorama.info/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml

Answer (score 5):

You can also use -exec option

```
find . -name test -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -r ./**/test/
```

The trailing slash means that it will only match directories. Test is beforehand with:

```
printf '%s\n' ./**/test/
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are using [gnu find](http://www.softpanorama.info/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml), you can use -delete option:

`find . -name test -delete`

which is easier to remember.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer points out, you can attempt to find all *directories* with the name `test` and delete them

```
find -name "test" -type d -delete
```

I ran into some issues with cross compatibility on Mac, so I used this equivalent command:

```
find -path "*/test" -type d -delete
```

- **-path**: looks for a pattern in the fully qualified filename.

In either case however, if any of the directories named `test` have files in them, `find` will complain that the `Directory is not empty`, and will fail to remove the directory.

If you intended to **delete all of the files** including the `test` directory, then we can use the same trick to delete all of the files inside directories named `test` first.

```
find -path "*/test/*" -delete
```

The pattern: `"*/test/*"`, will ensure we only delete files inside a directory named `/test/`.  Once the directories are empty, we can go ahead and delete the directories using the first command:

```
find -path "*/test" -type d -delete
```

**Example:**

```
$ tree
.
├── mytest
│   └── test
│       └── blah.txt
├── test
│   ├── bar.jpg
│   └── dir
│       └── bar.bak
└── testdir
    └── baz.c

5 directories, 4 files

$ find -path "*/test" -type d -delete
$ tree
.
├── mytest
│   └── test
├── test
└── testdir
    └── baz.c

4 directories, 1 file

$ find -name "test" -type d -delete
$ tree
.
├── mytest
└── testdir
    └── baz.c

2 directories, 1 file
```