# Are there limits to file length piped from find to xargs or using find -exec +

Tags: linux, shell, find

In question [ [Find and delete all the directories named "test" in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/602385/find-and-delete-all-the-directories-named-test-in-linux/602386) ] on this site, the best answer talks about using these two commands:

```
find . -name test -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --
find . -name test -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

because they will call rm with a *list* of directory instead of invoking it many times individually.

Since I cannot comment there due to low reputation, I ask here in a new question:

*Is there any limit on the number of files that can be passed to rm using these techniques (aside from realistic system resource bounds)?*

From the shell, a command like 'rm *' can exceed the shell's maximum command-line length, but do limits like that apply to this usage of find + or via a pipe to xargs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.

The long answer:
- Find will run the command specified by exec for every match, so if your find turns up 20 files, it will run 20 seperate instances of rm.
- xargs will determine the maximum command length for your shell and add arguments within these limits as you can see with the output of `xargs --show-limits`

`mtak@frisbee:~$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 4050 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091054
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2087004
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072`

Comment: Using the + in find's -exec will cause it to pass a list rather than invoke rm for _each_ file. It seems to pass ~128k of filenames at a time, so it apparently has similar logic to xargs. Thank you for pointing out that option to xargs!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I always use find with the `-exec rm {} \;` option.

Comment: I did too, and it's slow when deleting thousands of files, so I want to start using the + but was worried about it. Your answer about xargs made me think to write a test.pl to use instead of calling 'rm', which reported the number of args and their length -- so I could verify it behaved intelligently like xargs.